# How do i decide on the option parameters when using PSO pyswarms

Tags: python, particle-swarm

im trying to use binary pso package from pyswarms to conduct a text classification.

however I am a bit stuck on what parameters i should use?

c1 :float 
cognitive parameter
c2 :float
social parameter
w :float
inertia parameter
k :int
number of neighbors to be considered. Must be a positive integer less than n_particles
p: int {1,2}

These are the default parameters:

```
options = {'c1': 0.5, 'c2': 0.5, 'w':0.9, 'k': 30, 'p':2}
```

is there a specific way i need to choose them? so far ive honestly playing around with different parameters randomly.

Comment: the best place to start is here:  https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io

Comment: I feel the package [documentation](https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyswarms.single.html) does not adequately serve the user. It is unclear how (c1, c2, w) fit into the cited reference: https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GA/homeworks/hw3/_reading6%201995%20particle%20swarming.pdf